# How to test a promise has a catch method defined?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a method that returns a promise.

```js
doStuf() { 
  return somePromise
    .then(...)
    .catch(e => {...}) 
}
```

I want to write a test that makes sure the promise returned by the `doStuff` method has a catch method.

How to do that ?

Comment: That's not really a useful thing to test. What you want to test is how the promise behaves in case of an error. Does it end in an error, or does it return a useful value? The rule for unit tests is that you want to *test behaviour, not implementation.*

Comment: You want to assert catch is called on the Promise? perhaps spy the method call https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.5.0/spy-call/. But why test that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a useful thing to test. Consider that `doStuf` may be refactored later into something more multi-layered, where several `then`-`catch` chains may exist, or the implementation will change in some other ways.

You don't actually want to test the *implementation*, because you can simply look at it to *see* whether the promise has a `catch`. No, you want to test the *behaviour* of `doStuf`. You want to assert that `doStuf` returns a promise, and that that promise returns the expected value given certain input. E.g.:

```
doStuf('foo').then(r => /* assert r equals expected outcome */)
doStuf('bar').catch(r => /* assert r equals expected error */)
```